# Windows 10 Home Language Issue

Tags: windows-10, installation, language, input-languages, language-pack

I've just bought a USB copy of Windows 10 Home from [aria.co.uk](https://www.aria.co.uk/). For some reason, they have sent a German copy. On the USB stick, it says:

> WIN 10 German Home/Pro

Does anyone know if I can simply change the language to English during the installation?  I have read about not being able to if it is a single language version,  but I don't know how to tell if it is or not before installation.  I wouldn't want to go through the installation if it cannot be changed.

Thanks people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the normal DVD/USB drives are only in 1 language, but you can [add new MUIs to it with DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows).

The better solution is to get a new [English ISO of Windows 10 v1703](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, presumably the key that came with the German version can still be used on the English version?

Comment: You can download the ISO, with a specific default language pack, with the Media Creation Tool also.

Comment: @AdamB - Windows 10 license keys are not connected to the language except for `Windows 10 Home Single Language`.  If you have Windows 10 Home then you can install ANY Windows 10 Home ISO you want.

Comment: If you change the browser profile, and view [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) website and change the profile to a  non-Windows browser.  You can download the ISO directly from Microsoft any language you want.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound just to be clear, the box doesn't mention Single Language on it anywhere, so is it safe to assume that it is not the SL version?

Comment: @AdamB - That is only something you can determine.  You need to determine if a key to  `Windows 10 Home` installation or to a German `Windows 10 Home Single Language` installation.  Viewing the properties of the computer normally tells you the edition of the installation.

Comment: @Ramhound there is NO Single Language in German langauge, so the Home is the full Home

Comment: Thanks guys, I downloaded an English version from the MS website, installed that and used the key provided with the German version. All worked fine. So far as I can tell, Single Language versions will be explicitly marked "Microsoft Windows Single Language". Thanks for your helps.